# Set value in mongodb array element

Tags: java, mongodb, criteria-api, mongotemplate

I have a document like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "second",
            "conversationId" : "1",
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2015-03-01T20:16:30.991Z"),
            "text" : "cool text",
            "operatorId" : "operatorId",
            "clientId" : "clientId",
            "fromClient" : true
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have to change the text value to "coolest text". I'm using Spring's MongoTemplate with Criteria api and wrote the code below

```
mongoOps.upsert(
                query(where("_id").is(message.getConversationId()))
                        .addCriteria(where("messages.$._id").is(message.getId())),
                new Update().set("text", message.getText()), ConversationDocument.class);
```

but nothing changed.

mongoOps.findOne(query(where("_id").is(message.getConversationId())), ConversationDocument) returns exactly the same document I want to change.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have used:

**messages._id** in the query instead of **messages.$._id**

and

**messages.$.text** instead of **text** in your Update method.

Give it a try (I have tested, it works).

```
Query query = query(
                new Criteria().andOperator(
                        where("_id").is(conversation.getId()),
                        where("messages._id").is(message.getId())
                )
        );

mongoOps.upsert(query, new Update().set("messages.$.text", "coolest text"), Conversation.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what I do, get the document, update the value(s) then call update, it works fine, which makes the code much simple and easy to debug.

```
ConversationDocument doc =  mongoOps.findOne(query(where("_id").is(message.getConversationId())), ConversationDocument); 

//* you must have methods inside of your ConverstionDocument to set the values in the messages object
Message message doc.getMessage();
message.setText("cool text");

mongoOps.update(doc);
```

Comment: It's cool but the full document can have a large size, therefore I want to use update query.